# SQL mediumtext count substrings from list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to develop kind of "bad words" plugin for MyBB forum, and I would like to ask you for help with the SQL command.

Lets simplyfy the solution to relevant columns only:

> Table: words
>  
>    Column1: number, recordID 
>    Column2: varchar, badWord
>    -this table contains just a list of not permitted words
>    
>    Table: posts 
>   Column1: number, postID 
>   Column2: number, userID 
>   Column3:mediumtext, postBody
>   -here is id of post, who sent it and the text of post.
>   
>   Table: users 
>   Column1: number, userID 
>   Column2: number, badWordCount
>   -basic usere table was expanded by my column containing number of bad words

Now.
Does exist a **pure SQL** solution for this request?

**For every row in "posts", select mediumtext column "postBody". Once inside, loop through "words" table. Everytime you intercept any bad word, add +1 to users.badWordCount by id of user.**

In one post, there can be many different (or same) bad words. I need to find all of them and count them and then add the number of bad words to each user by whom was the post created

For demonstration:

> words (id, badWord):
>    1, fck
>    2, btch
>    
>    Posts (postID,userID,postBody):
>    1,1,Hello, fck you btch
>    2,2,no, fck you you fck
>    3,1,Aaah, fck you

After execution, it should result in

> Users (userID,badwordCount)
>   1,3
>   2,2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a purely SQL method, although this is probably not the best approach.

```
select userId,
       sum(length(replace(concat(' ', w.postBody, ' '), concat(' ', w.badword, ' '), concat(w.word, '123'))) -
           length(concat(' ', w.postBody, ' '))
          )
from posts p join
     words w
     on concat(' ', w.postBody, ' ') like concat('% ', w.badword, '% ')
group by userId;
```

The spaces are to delimit the words in the text.  This may not be necessary for your purposes.  Without the spaces the logic looks like:

```
select userId,
       sum(length(replace(w.postBody, w.word, concat(w.badword, ' '))) -
           length(w.postBody)
          )
from posts p join
     words w
     on w.postBody like concat('% ', w.badword, '% ')
group by userId;
```

The idea is to look for the word in the post using `like`.  Then the number of words is counted by replace the word with something one longer in length.  Then, measuring the change in length after the replacement.

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke . . . Yes, the first version had the subtraction in the wrong order.

Comment: **from posts p join
     words w** .. what posts, p, words, and w stands for here? Asking cause you have shortened some table naming and so on, from my post, and the tables and naming in my solution is different, of course, so to be sure, it will work after I change table and columns naming .. thanks

Comment: Well, I tried to got through your piece of code and I am not sure, what means what especially **w.word** because in my post there were no "word". Actually, I got lost in this snippet. Please, could you be so kind and rewrite the code for me with exact columns and tables? Table mybb_users, columns uid, badWordCount; Table mybb_posts, columns pid, uid, message; Table mybb_badwords, columns bid, badword; I would be very greatful for that :)

Comment: tried to rewrite: `select uid,
       sum(length(replace(mybb_posts.message, "123", concat(mybb_badwords.badword, ' ')) -
           length(mybb_posts.message)
          )
from mybb_posts p join
     mybb_badwords w
     on mybb_posts.message like concat('% ', mybb_badwords.badword, '% ')
group by userId;` and got a syntax error **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from mybb_posts p join mybb_badwords w on mybb_posts.message like conc' at line 5**